# measuring concurent loop times in erlang

Tags: concurrency, erlang

I create a round of processes in erlang and wish to measure the time that it took for the first message to pass throigh the network and the entire message series, each time the first node gets the message back it sends another one.
right now in the first node i have the following code:

```
    receive
stop->
    io:format("all processes stopped!~n"),
    true;
start->
    statistics(runtime),
    Son!{number, 1},
    msg(PID, Son, M, 1);
{_, M} ->
    {Time1, _} = statistics(runtime),
    io:format("The last message has arrived after ~p! ~n",[Time1*1000]),
    Son!stop;
```

of course i start the statistics when sending the first message.
as you can see i use the Time_Since_Last_Call for the first message loop and wish to use the Total_Run_Time for the entire run, the problem is that Total_Run_Time is accumulative since i start the statistics for the first time.
The second thought i had in mind is using another process with 2 receive loops getting the times for each one adding them and printing but i'm sure that erlang can do better than this.
i guess the best method to solve this is somehow flush the Total_Run_Time, but i couldn't find how this could be done. any ideas how this can be tackled?

Answer (score 2):

One way to measure round-trip times would be to send a timestamp along with each message. When the first node receives the message, it can then measure the round-trip time, calculating `Total_Run_Time - Timestamp`.

To calculate the total run time, I would memorize the first timestamp in the process state (or dictionary), and calculate the total run time when stopping the test.

Besides, given that you mention the network, are you sure that the CPU time (which is what `statistics(runtime)` calculates is what you're after?  Perhaps, wall clock time would be more appropriate.